# How can I fix the problem with the math font in adobe acrobat

Tags: math-fonts

I am making a slide with latex beamer, and I would like to use FiraMath as the font for the math environment. Everything seems to be smooth as no warning during the generation of this document in texstudio. But when I try to open this pdf with adobe acrobat, it is unable to extract embedded font even though I have install FiraMath-Regular.

How can I solve this problem?

I use the following code to set the font for my beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x_{k} - b_{k-1}x_{k-1} \geqslant 0, \for k = 1, 2, \cdots, m
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When I tried to make some symbols, like $\cdots$, it can be shown in the viewer inside texstudio or other pdf viewers like google chrome, but cannot be recognized in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Do you get a specific error message in Acrobat? What is the LaTeX code of the document that generates the error?

Comment: Show a small but *complete*  example. Don't let us guess what you are doing. Also say how you are compiling.